# Subset Sum Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

```
def subset(array, target):
    sol = [[False for x in range(target + 1)] for x in range(len(array) + 1)]
    for i in range(len(array)+1):
        sol[i][0] = True
    for i in range(1,(len(array)+1)):
        for j in range(1, target+1):
            if (j - array[i-1] >= 0):
                sol[i][j] = sol[i-1][j] | sol[i-1][j - array[i-1]]
            else:
                sol[i][j] = sol[i-1][j]
    printSub(sol, array, target)
    return sol[len(array)][target]

def printSub(sol, array, target):
    if(sol[len(array)][target]):
        print("Found!")
        i = len(array)
        j = target
        while(j!=0):
            if(sol[i-1][j] == True):
                i-=1
            else:
                print(array[i-1], end = " ")
                j = j - array[i-1]
    else:
        print("No combination found! ")
```

I've a working code of the subset problem, which can print numbers if it finds a subset equal to the desired target.

1. I want to print all possible subsets for a given target, I don't understand what to change for that.
2. How do I make it work for negative numbers?
3. The time complexity is O(len(array) * target) and the space I believe is the same. Is there some way to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

**1)**Change the `printsub` function for that that is loop an `i`through 1 to `len(array)` and use`if(sol[i][target])` instead of `(sol[len(array)][target])`.

**2)**After the double loops-

```
for i in range(1,(len(array)+1)):
    for j in range(1, target+1):
```

add a condition that checks if `array[i-1]`is negative or not `if` it is positive no need to change anything `else` replace `j` by `target+2-j`in

```
 if (j - array[i-1] >= 0):
            sol[i][j] = sol[i-1][j] | sol[i-1][j - array[i-1]]
```

**3)**Here's link to same ques-
[Reducing time complexity of 0-1 Knapsack problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879631/reducing-time-complexity-of-knapsack-01-while-using-dp-algorithm)